# What are legal ramifications around using Windows on Mac via Bootcamp?

Tags: windows, macos, mac, boot-camp, legal

Very often Windows is shipped with a PC. As I understand I can't use that copy of Windows on my Mac. What can I use? Would Windows OEM be a good choice? Is 'normal' version of Windows okay for this purpose? If I want to run Windows either via Boot Camp or Parallels does it mean I need to have to 2 copies?

Edit: I'm not asking here whether it's legal to install Windows on Mac. I want to know the exact legal details of that. I am a freelancer and I can't afford penalites associated with illegal use of software.

Comment: Yes, you need another copy for your Mac and cannot reuse the copy that came pre-installed on your PC.

Comment: Additional info: - You can use the version you purchase for Boot Camp & also use the same BC install inside Parallels, rather than have to have 2 versions of windows, one in BC, the other in Parallels [so long as you shut down the Parallels version before switching to BC, rather than suspending it.] 1 license, 1 'machine', just accessed from 2 'locations'.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the copy of Windows that came with the computer is called an OEM copy and is tied to the machine it came from.  It cannot be used on any other legally.

You can buy a retail copy (called retail or FRR) and it can be used on the mac.  Some places also sell OEM copies that are meant to be purchased and installed on machines people build.  Technically you can use that if you buy some sort of hardware with it (flash drive...) and use that for your mac.